# H2O deeplearning with class imbalance

Tags: r, machine-learning, deep-learning, h2o

I am using the H2O deeplearning Feed Forward Deep Neural network for doing a binary classification. My classes are  highly imbalanced and I want to use the parameters like

> balance_classes, class_sampling_factors

Can any body give me a reproducible example about how to specifically intialize these parameters to handle class imbalance problems.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, here is the full, reproducible, example:

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init()

data(iris)  #Not required?
iris <- iris[1:120,] #Remove 60% of virginica
summary(iris$Species) #50/50/20

d <- as.h2o(iris)
splits = h2o.splitFrame(d,0.8,c("train","test"), seed=77)
train = splits[[1]]
test = splits[[2]]
summary(train$Species)  #41/41/14
summary(test$Species)  #9/9/6

m1 = h2o.randomForest(1:4, 5, train, model_id ="RF_defaults", seed=1)
h2o.confusionMatrix(m1)

m2 = h2o.randomForest(1:4, 5, train, model_id ="RF_balanced", seed=1,
  balance_classes = TRUE)
h2o.confusionMatrix(m2)

m3 = h2o.randomForest(1:4, 5, train, model_id ="RF_balanced", seed=1,
  balance_classes = TRUE,
  class_sampling_factors = c(1, 1, 2.5)
  )
h2o.confusionMatrix(m3)
```

The first lines initialize H2O, then I deliberately modify the iris data set to throw away 60% of one of the 3 classes, to create an imbalance.

The next few lines load that data into H2O, and create a 80%/20% train/test data split. The seed was chosen deliberately, so that in the training data *virginica* is 14.58% of the data, compared to 16.67% in the original data, and 25% in the test data.

I then train three random forest models. `m1` is all defaults, and its confusion matrix looks like this:

```
           setosa versicolor virginica  Error     Rate
setosa         41          0         0 0.0000 = 0 / 41
versicolor      0         39         2 0.0488 = 2 / 41
virginica       0          1        13 0.0714 = 1 / 14
Totals         41         40        15 0.0312 = 3 / 96
```

Nothing to see here: it uses the data it finds.

Now here is the same output for `m2`, which switches on `balance_classes`. You can see it is over-sampled the *virginica* class to get them as balanced as possible. (The right-most columns says 41,41,40 instead of 41,41,14 as in the previous output.)

```
           setosa versicolor virginica  Error      Rate
setosa         41          0         0 0.0000 =  0 / 41
versicolor      0         41         0 0.0000 =  0 / 41
virginica       0          2        38 0.0500 =  2 / 40
Totals         41         43        38 0.0164 = 2 / 122
```

In `m3` we still switch on `balance_classes`, but also tell it the truth of the situation. I.e. that the actual data is 16.67% *virginica*, not the 14.58% it sees in the `train` data. The confusion matrix for `m3` shows that it therefore turned the 14 *virginica* samples into 37 samples instead of 40 samples.

```
           setosa versicolor virginica  Error      Rate
setosa         41          0         0 0.0000 =  0 / 41
versicolor      0         41         0 0.0000 =  0 / 41
virginica       0          2        35 0.0541 =  2 / 37
Totals         41         43        35 0.0168 = 2 / 119
```

How did I know to write `c(1, 1, 2.5)`, and not `c(2.5, 1, 1)` or `c(1, 2.5, 1)` ? The docs say it must be in "lexicographic order". You can find out what that order is with:

```
h2o.levels(train$Species)
```

which tells me:

```
[1] "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica"
```

The opinion bit: `balance_classes` is good to switch on, but `class_sampling_factors` should only be used when you have a really good reason to believe that your training data is not representative.

**NOTE:** Code and explanation adapted from my upcoming book, Practical Machine Learning with H2O.

Comment: How do we calculate the `class_sampling_factors`? For example if I have dataste which contains 1000 datapoints from positive class and 50000 datapoints from negative class, what will be the sampling factors here and how will I compute it?

Comment: @Newbie They are just how much you want to over-sample (or under-sample if less than 1.0) each class. So, in your case, I guess you want to over-sample each "positive" sample 50 times? So you give `class_sampling_factors = c(50, 1)`  (assuming "positive" is the first class). BUT NOTE: that is the default behaviour of just setting `balance_classes`! Only bother setting `class_sampling_factors` if you need a different ratio.